# CONCAT in SQL Server 2008 r3

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I have to concat a few fields to generate a unique key, and in order to do that I want to combine 3 fields with different data types: `integer`, `date` and `string`.

What I used in SQL Server 2012:

```
CONCAT(PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID, '-', PMEOBJECT.FROMDATE, '-', PMEBUILDING.NAME) AS OBJECTIDKEY
```

Any ideas how to write this in SQL Server 2008?

edit: also NULLS have to be taken into account.
editedit: I added ISNULL(PMEOBJECT.FROMDATE, '') in between to make it work. Thanks all.

Comment: You'll need to cast the non-strings to string and then use "+" to concat them.

Comment: You would not use `CONCAT` for this even in SQL Server 2012, because you really don't want to rely on whatever is the default conversion format for a `DATE` (which can vary with language). Use `CONVERT` explicitly.

Comment: Why not just use a surrogate key?

Comment: Keep in mind, CONCAT will implicitly convert NULL to an empty string.  Using '+' does not do that.  If you concatenate strings using '+', and any one of them is NULL, then the whole result will be NULL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. Now I actually did get into problems with the NULL's. I need to concatenate a few columns to create a unique key of which some of the columns have NULL values. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use '+' to concatenate columns, but remember to cast non string types (`int`, `date` etc.) to a string type (for example `varchar`), otherwise an error would occurr (since SQL Sever would try to actually add values):

```
select cast(PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID as varchar(50)) + '-' 
     + cast(PMEOBJECT.FROMDATE as varchar(50)) + '-'
     + PMEBUILDING.NAME as OBJECTIDKEY
```

For `date` columns you'll probably want to define a custom format, so it is probably better to use `CONVERT` instead of `CAST`.

For example to obtain the classic `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` ODBC format you can use this:

```
select cast(PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID as varchar(50)) + '-' 
     + convert(varchar(50), PMEOBJECT.FROMDATE, 120) + '-'
     + PMEBUILDING.NAME as OBJECTIDKEY
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). In this context it means `VARCHAR(30)`, but that's not at all obvious.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you are right, thank you for the advice.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense and it works, for some of the columns.. However I now concatenate columns of which some of them have NULL values. How to concatenate columns without NULL overruling the entire column and other values in 2008?

Comment: @titatovenaar What should happen when a NULL is found? A blank should appear (`objid--name`) or the hypen should also be removed (`objid-name`)? Can you please add some samples to your question?

Comment: Found the answer, sorry for bringing this up again. I used: select cast(PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID as varchar(50)) + '-' 
     + cast(ISNULL(PMEOBJECT.FROMDATE, '') as varchar(50)) + '-'
     + PMEBUILDING.NAME as OBJECTIDKEY

Answer (score 0):

You can also have type problem while using "+" though you will have to use sometimes convert(varchar, expression) :)